# How to change PHP page name in URL using .htaccess?

Tags: php, .htaccess

how to change php page name in url from htaccess  this is my real url

```
site.com/folder/hi.php
```

I want to change the name (hi) to (hello) without changing my real file name that is (hi) so the url have to be.

```
site.com/folder/hello.php
```

And how can i call this link in php index page ??? Like word press page name changes

Please help.

using this but not working

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^folder/([0-9]+)/?$ /hi.php?vp=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Comment: your regex in the rewrite rule only looks for numbers, not characters like a-z so it never trigger for hello, change it to `[0-9a-z]+`

Comment: This question is unclear, and example doesn't correspond to question. There are many similar questions about htaccess. Remember that question quality = answer quality. That's why You should improve it.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing you want to have `http://example.com/folder/hello.php/1234` in the url bar of your browser. If you go to that url, the page will load `/folder/hi.php?vp=1234` on your server, but the url doesn't change.

You would then need to use a rule like the following in the `.htaccess` file in your www-root:

```
RewriteRule ^folder/hello\.php/([0-9]+)/?$ /folder/hi.php?vp=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

The first argument has a `\.` in it. `.` would match any character, but we want to match an actual dot. `\.` is an escaped dot character and therefore only matches the actual dot. The second argument is an absolute url from your www-root.

Make sure that mod_rewrite is enabled on your installation of Apache, and that you are allowed to use .htaccess files. If `hi.php` checks vp with `$_GET['vp']` or something similar, this should work fine. If it checks it using `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` then it won't (and it never will work).